Multiple smaller capacitors on power rail for NeoPixel / WS2812B strip
I read in the AdaFruit guide that a 500-1000uF capacitor is recommended on the power rail.
However, electrolytic capacitors in this capacitance are quite large. Depending on the length of the strip, would 5-10 100uF ceramic SMD capacitors be okay instead?

The idea of the capacitor is to provide bulk capacitance to the strip. However since Neo pixel addressable LEDs already have local bypass capacitors, I'm skeptical that provides much benefit unless the lines from the DC power supply are very long or very lossy.

Many smaller capacitors on the strip would be OK. However, large value ceramics need their rating interpretting correctly. The capacitance is quoted at zero bias and falls at rated bias, down to 25% is not uncommon for the smallest packages. Be prepared to use four times the number of capacitors you would expect to get the required capacitance. If you happen to be using larger packages which 'only' drop to 33% or 50% of rated, then having extra rail capacitance is not a problem.
I don't know why capacitors are allowed to be advertised in this way, with the voltage coefficient hidden from the headline specifications, the capacitance quoted at zero voltage rather than rated voltage, but they are. As SMD capacitors have got smaller, new dielectrics have been developed which have colossal dielectric constant, but also colossal voltco. You need to download the full specifications from manufacturers, and read the specs for the specific value in the specific package to get the true voltco figures.
